# how to solve this error? (collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld')

Tags: compiling, make, fortran

I'm a beginner and I need your help.
I use Ubuntu18.04 and want to install Orient package for molecular calculation.
https://gitlab.com/anthonyjs/orient
I get this error when compiling it with gfortran compiler.

```
gfortran -o orient-5.0.09 -L/home/src/Mesa-6.2.1/lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  -L/usr/lib \
         -static-libgfortran -static-libgcc <something>.o -llapack -lblas -lpthread -lgfortran -lc -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lm
```

`collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'`
`compilation terminated.`

I think this indicates linkers for compilation does not work properly.
However, I don't know what I should do next, although I researched questions of similar errors.

Thank you for your advice.

---

Let me add some information.

```
$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
 warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ gfortran--print-prog-name=ld
ld

$ type -a ld
-bash: type: ld: not found
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the outputs of `gfortran --version`, `gfortran --print-prog-name=ld` and `type -a ld`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added.

Comment: Thanks - so does `/usr/bin/ld` exist and is `/usr/bin` in your `PATH` (`echo $PATH`)?

Comment: Yes, /usr/bin/ld exists and contains only two files, liblapack.a and librefblas.a.
/usr/bin also exists in my PATH.

Comment: `/usr/bin/ld` should be an executable program (provided by the `binutils` package) not a directory containing archive files - how did you get in this mess?

Comment: I miss making a directory named ld, when I got an error message '/usr/bin/ld not found'. Then, I removed the directory and install binutils as you say.
The error can be solved and I compile successfully.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any issues compiling this software as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential gfortran \ 
liblapack-dev libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev

cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://gitlab.com/anthonyjs/orient.git
cd orient
make
```

After compilation it runs normally:

```
$ ./bin/orient
               ORIENT version 5.0.09  (4d48c82)

                             by

                        Anthony Stone

                   with contributions from
Andreas Dullweber, Ola Engkvist, Elena Fraschini, Matt Hodges,
   Andy Meredith, David Nutt, Paul Popelier and David Wales

      Compiled with gfortran on 03 November 2019 at 19:21:08

Starting at 19:21:51 on 3 Nov 2019  

Parameters for this version:
Maximum rank of multipole moments:            5
Maximum rank of polarizabilities:             4
```

You may have some missing dependencies.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I have realized that I misunderstood the meaning of error messages.